# Angularjs $http post error err_name_resolution_failed when internet is reconnected using $window.navigator.onLine

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using Angular $http to post data to the backend. The data is generated every second.

But the user's internet is down frequently. So I use a queue to cache the data and then $scope.$watch the connection status. If internet is available again, then I post the data one by one in the queue using the following codes:

```
$scope.$watch('onlineStatus.isOnline()', function(online) {

  if (online) {
    $scope.online = true;
    // if dataQueue is not empty, post the data one by one
    while (dataQueue.length > 0) {
      Data.create(vm.urlJobname, dataQueue.shift()); // anjular service
    }
  } else {
    $scope.online = false;
  }
});
```

I have tested that the online/offline status works. However, when the internet is reconnected, Angularjs shows error say:

`POST https://XXXX.com/api/realtimeData net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED`

Do not undertstand what does this mean?

Any idea?

Comment: The error is saying that the DNS lookup for XXXX.com failed ... maybe because the operating system is still working on establishing the connection. How do you determine that the OS has reconnected, and what happens if you wait a little bit before trying to POST the data?

Comment: yes, you are right. it is still woking on the internet connection. I am using `$window.navigator.onLine` and watch it the connection status. When I setTimeout with 2 seconds, then it works, thanks a lot for pointing that @SunilD.